# How to put two decimals in cell with type of percent

Tags: python, openpyxl

Recently I spent some time solving this issue. If you face same problem this might be helpful and you will get a clue how to solve the problem.

I have openpyxl version 2.2.2
I need to write percent value with 2 digits after dot into a cell. Value should be seen in Excel as '3.14%' - type of percentage, two decimals digits after dot
Here is my first attempt:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook(guess_types=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet(index = 0, title = "MyTable")
ws['A1'].value = '3.14%'
ws['A1'].number_format

>> '0%'
```

Seems fine unless you do not know what does '0%' mean
Here how it looks in excel:
[image]

Comment: guess-types is really designed for doing something like importing from CSV. It is strongly advised against to use it in other contexts.

Answer (score 22):

All you need are:

- adding number formating
- not to use guess_types parameter

Here is the final state:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(index = 0, title = "MyTable")
ws['A1'].value = '3.14%'
ws['A1'].number_format = '0.00%'
```

Here is documentation for other used formats:
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styles.html

Comment: It's really cool that openpyxl allows to format already written cell. This is why I switched from xlsxwriter to openpyxl. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: FWIW, at least as of version `2.6.2`, I found that the value should be a float to get the output Excel file to show as a percent without the `Number Stored as Text` warning message you see when mousing over the cell. So `'3.14%'` should be `0.0314`.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [built-in style numbers](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html).

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet(index = 0, title = "MyTable")
ws['A1'].value = '0.0314'

from openpyxl.styles.numbers import FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
# with two decimal places. Will output 3.14%
ws['A1'].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00

from openpyxl.styles.numbers import FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
# with no decimal places. Will output 3%
ws['A1'].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE
```

Or use [build it styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#using-builtin-styles). it will output 3%

```
ws['A1'].style = "Percent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a percent format with a certain decimal place. Tested on python 3.9.

```
def percent_format_with_decimals(decimal_places: int):
    returnFormat = "0."
    for i in range(decimal_places):
        returnFormat += "0"
    return returnFormat + "%"
```

Comment: This is only tested with converting float numbers to percentages, although my best guess is that it would also work with the asker's case.